# Very Slow ng build --prod in Docker

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, angular-cli-v6

When I try to build an angular7 project inside docker it takes around 40 minutes. The line that takes 40 minutes is

ng build --prod

92% chunk asset optimization TerserPlugin

I've ran ng build --prod outside docker on the same laptop it takes 2 minutes.

I've tried adding --build-optimizer false

and --sourceMap=false

Does not make any difference

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:carbon
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@6.1.0
COPY . .
RUN ng build --prod
EXPOSE 4200
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --timeout=30s --retries=20 CMD curl --fail http://localhost:4200 || exit 1
```

Comment: about 2-3 minutes

Comment: Why not you build your angular app before running docker build>

Comment: Do you have the docker logs?

Comment: @wentjun Doing a build in host machine and then copying over the conents is probably not a good idea.

Comment: I'm confused...why is the angular 6.1.0 cli being used? I think build issues were addressed in the newer cli version [6795](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6795)

Comment: @xyz Hmm.. I am currently running ng build on my docker image too, rather than my host machine. I might have an idea of why it is a bad idea, but could you please give more details? Or show show me some article that explains it? TBH I am a bit new when it comes to docker, so I still need some help when it comes to that.

Comment: @RichS I've tried it with the latest angular cli 7 there was no difference

Comment: `docker logs [container name]` would be useful. Hopefully, it will support what @Daniel suspects to be the root cause (`docker ps -a` to help get the container name)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This issue with extremely slow builds is *almost always* related to the build process lacking memory.

Node will not allocate a lot of memory for a single process (512mb on 32bit systems and 1gb on 64bit systems), but running `ng build` with production settings uses a lot of memory.

You can use the Node paramteter `max_old_space_size` to set how much RAM you allow the process to use, but you have to pass the parameter directly to node so replace

```
ng build --prod
```

with

```
node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
```

it will allocate up to 8GB of RAM for the process, which will make it run much faster.

You can also add this to your scripts in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  ....
  "build:prod": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod"
 }
```

(*If increasing the memory limit doesn't work, try running `ng build --prod --verbose` to see exact timings for different phases of the compilation*)

Comment: here is a nice article (angular agnostic one, just about nodejs) https://developer.ibm.com/articles/nodejs-memory-management-in-container-environments/

Comment: And if you're on a Mac, don't forget to increase Docker's memory limit too.

Comment: don't works with docker :(

Answer (score 3):

As Daniel mention in answer you can use node parameter `--max_old_space_size` but I prefer to set it up via environment var:

```
NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096
```

Comment: don't works with docker :(

Comment: @JRichardsz pass it to node this way in your package.json:  "start": "export NODE_OPTIONS=\"--openssl-legacy-provider --max-old-space-size=8192\"; ng serve --host 0.0.0.0"

Comment: Thanks @grantwparks I will try it!