# How to speed up Angular's dev server startup in Docker?

Tags: angular, docker

I have an issue running an Angular app through a Docker container while the source is attached via volume. The `ng serve` startup is incredibly slow.

My goal is to dockerize the development process (on Windows). For reference, the dummy project is available on GitHub: https://github.com/csgulyas/node-docker-angular

I have the following versions of things:

```
Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe
docker-compose version 1.27.2, build 18f557f9

Running under WSL2:
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04           Running         2
  docker-desktop-data    Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
```

I've not done anything other than generating an angular project via `ng new`, and added

the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:12.18.4-alpine AS dev # latest LTS node

EXPOSE 4242 # just so it isn't 4200
EXPOSE 49153 # apparently this is for change detection

USER node

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/.npm-global
ENV PATH=/home/node/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
WORKDIR /app

CMD ["ng", "serve", "--port", "4242", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--disable-host-check", "--poll", "1000"]
```

and the `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.4'

services:
    angularapp:
        container_name: angularapp
        image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapp
        build:
            context: ./demo-frontend
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "4200:4242"
            - "49153:49153"
        environment:
            NODE_OPTIONS: --max_old_space_size=4096
        volumes:
            - ./demo-frontend:/app
```

While monitoring the output of the container, I get the following

```
angularapp    | 2020-09-29T13:18:32.802573300Z Your global Angular CLI version (10.1.3) is greater than your local
angularapp    | 2020-09-29T13:18:32.802597400Z version (9.1.12). The local Angular CLI version is used.
angularapp    | 2020-09-29T13:18:32.802601300Z
angularapp    | 2020-09-29T13:18:32.802603800Z To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
angularapp    | 2020-09-29T13:19:50.000172200Z WARNING: This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications
angularapp    | 2020-09-29T13:19:50.000214200Z locally. It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.
angularapp    | 2020-09-29T13:19:50.000221200Z
angularapp    | 2020-09-29T13:19:50.000223800Z Binding this server to an open connection can result in compromising your application or
angularapp    | 2020-09-29T13:19:50.000226100Z computer. Using a different host than the one passed to the "--host" flag might result in
angularapp    | 2020-09-29T13:19:50.000228700Z websocket connection issues. You might need to use "--disableHostCheck" if that's the
angularapp    | 2020-09-29T13:19:50.000231000Z case.
angularapp    | 2020-09-29T13:19:50.000709400Z WARNING: Running a server with --disable-host-check is a security risk. See https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server-middleware-security-issues-1489d950874a for more information.
angularapp    | 2020-09-29T13:20:10.731395000Z
angularapp    | 2020-09-29T13:20:10.731441600Z chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 57.7 kB [initial] [rendered]
angularapp    | 2020-09-29T13:20:10.731452000Z chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 141 kB [initial] [rendered]
angularapp    | 2020-09-29T13:20:10.731457200Z chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
angularapp    | 2020-09-29T13:20:10.731461400Z chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 12.7 kB [initial] [rendered]
angularapp    | 2020-09-29T13:20:10.731464600Z chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 2.71 MB [initial] [rendered]
angularapp    | 2020-09-29T13:20:10.731468000Z Date: 2020-09-29T13:20:10.730Z - Hash: 71f01e77608773fbaa56 - Time: 11928ms
angularapp    | 2020-09-29T13:20:10.732294000Z ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on 0.0.0.0:4242, open your browser on http://localhost:4242/ **
angularapp    | 2020-09-29T13:20:10.732720500Z : Compiled successfully.
```

This is the output of the 2nd run of the container, the first one takes a bit longer for first time compilation I'm guessing. If you look at the 5th line, it took over a minute to progress the initialization, and start the compilation.

I've looked around what may be the cause, most common recommendation was to increase the memory limit of `node`. I did that in the compose file via environment variable.

Edit: It appears this is an issue with Windows, WSL2, and Docker volumes. I read about issues with file system access being slow from a container to the Windows host under WSL2. Ran the project in a cloud VSP under Ubuntu 20.04 and the Angular dev server spun up as fast as the cloud resources allowed it.

Comment: Are you on a MacOS host?  The Angular application ultimately runs in a browser, so it can't use Docker features like communicating with containers by name; what benefit would you get by running this in Docker as opposed to a local Node installation?

Comment: @DavidMaze Windows 10, as it says in the question. I want to have applications/services hosted by Docker in development time. This is an example for hosting the Angular application, it would be accompanied by backend/services/database in the compose file. Those are not relevant for the current issue.

Comment: Could it be something to do with this? [Very slow ng build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55757966/very-slow-ng-build-prod-in-docker) I'm trying to get a fix using that angle.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a problem of angular itself.

WSL2 [has an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4197) with filesystem performance on `/mnt`.

A little you can do is to add your project and `node` process to [Exclusion for Windows Defender](https://www.google.com/search?q=Add%20an%20exclusion%20to%20Windows%20Security). It might help a little, but don't expect too much.

For now, while the WSL performance issue is not fixed, I'd recommend to run development locally using `gitbash` and use docker only on production.